# Downvoting working answers disrespects community and OP

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I did my best to provide a working answer with additional information. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71718686/447901

If the answer does not work or is "bad" in some way, I am eager to acknowledge and correct or delete the answer. I do not want to lead an OP or the community in an unproductive direction.

What goal does a downvote with no explanation serve?

I know that the meta community does not want to require a comment or checklist as to why a downvote is appropriate. There will likely be many downvotes on this question, but I do not know what purpose it serves.

Comment: *"What goal does a downvote with no explanation serve?"* It lets you know that someone else thought the answer was unclear or not useful. It doesn't do any more or less than that. It certainly cannot be "disrespectful".

Comment: It also lets _other people_ know that the answer might not be worth reading, in the view of the voter.

Comment: If StackExchange ever wonders why StackOverflow has a reputation for not being a welcoming community, it should look into META. It would seem that some have taken this opportunity to downvote the working answer to ensure that my contribution is devalued. Keep calm and downvote on. You might want to delete this comment before anyone who could do anything about it can see it.

Comment: If anyone ever wonders why users who downvote avoid leaving a comment, they need look no further than your haughty rudeness, entitlement, and absolute arrogance about the idealized perfection of your answer.

Comment: @CodyGray, is it "haughty rudeness, entitlement, and absolute arrogance" to say that the answer works? I did not say it was "perfect" or "the best" or "the only way to do it".

Comment: @user16320675, it is not about the points. I could not care less about the points. What I do care about is the community. Downvotes tell the OP and community that the working answer "...might not be worth reading,..." according to jonrsharpe, but without indicating why.

Comment: There are multiple reasons to downvote an answer. It not working is only one possible reason to downvote. You seem to think your answer is so perfect that it should be immune to downvotes. I perceive that as arrogant. But beyond perception, the way you came out swinging judgment with this question, and then really dug in to start slinging dirt and casting aspersions on the community as a whole in the comments, well, that's just tangible evidence of why people might choose not to engage directly with you or users like you.

Comment: you may not care about the points, but that does not change the fact that from all viewers only 3 downvoted (sure, it would be better to know why...  and no one on meta can tell you why, only the users that downvoted; but that is how the site works)

Answer (score 34):

The question is tagged [jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jq) which ...

> is a sed-like tool for JSON data – you can use it to slice, filter, map, and transform structured data with the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends lets you play with text.

Your answer doesn't even mention jq and then goes on to run powershell.exe from a cmd batch script. That by itself doesn't seem like an overly effective way of solving that problem. Some might call that even *not useful* which is a reason to downvote. The community worked and the OP is signaled that your answer might not be the best.

Comment: It is not explained either why a loop is required in CMD(!?). A very heavy slow-to-start Windows process (powershell.exe) ***seems*** to be launched a lot of times (once per loop iteration). Perhaps someone thought it was a joke answer (a lot of people flipped their lids yesterday and went a bit crazy (April fool day)).